# How to choose the scaleType of ImageView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, scaletype

I have a `RecyclerView` displaying a bunch of images as thumbnails. The `width` and `height` of the images can vary, some are `1280x720` and some are `4128x2322`.

When I choose `scaleType="center"` for the `ImageView` in the XML layout, then my `4128x2322` images are shown perfectly (they occupy the whole screen as expected), but the `1280x720` images are displayed in a very cringe way (you can not see the image as a whole, only a part of it as if someone has zoomed in).

When I choose `scaleType="centerInside"`, then the `1280x720` images are shown perfectly (the whole image is shown and it looks like a real thumbnail image like the ones we know from apps like YouTube) but the `4128x2322` images are shrinked and that is not looking good.

What is the typical way to solve this problem so that my `ImageView` can adjust its `width` and `height` in a most appropriate way based on what the `width` and `height` are.

For the sake of completeness, here is my `image_list_item.xml` layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="image"
            type="com.celik.abdullah.learningdifferentscaletypesforimageview.Image" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:scaleType = "center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="center"
                tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                app:imageSrc="@{image.imageUrl}" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The `ImageView` is wrapped into a `FrameLayout` because I wanted to have some icons on top of it later. But that's unimportant for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Please add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in ImageView Tag...

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                app:imageSrc="@{image.imageUrl}" />
```